# Word press adds <div id="level-access-access-assistant-highlight-container">

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, lighthouse

I am using the Advanced Custom fields plugin in wordpress, and whenever I modify text fields on posts in chrome, wordpress appends `<div id="level-access-access-assistant-highlight-container">` to the end of my text. Doesn't really do anything except pop up as a lighthouse error telling me I have multiple elements with the same id.

Issue comes up on the latest versions of chrome, but doesn't happen in firefox/edge/ie

Has anyone else had this issue? Is there anything I can do to change it?

LINK: [here](https://preview.hr.wisc.edu/)

Comment: Use unique id in page there have arrived duplication ids.

Comment: The issue isn't me adding duplicate id's, wordpress/ wordpress' editor adds that line of text and I don't want it

Comment: yes but you have says in your comment : I have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: I understand, I delete them, but wordpress keeps adding them back each time I make additional edits.

Comment: is there a URL to share?

Comment: what other plugins are you using. try disabling all of them and see if the problem persists. also it might be a problem of your theme. try to narrow down bug options. by changing theme as well and see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Issue comes up on the latest versions of chrome, but doesn't happen in
>   firefox/edge/ie"

Then it may not be a server side issue but instead "id" is being inserted by a browser extension/add-on (to identify accessibility issues???) in your own Chrome browser. Check what browser extensions/add-ons you have installed for Chrome and try deactivating them.